Help with LED VU meter

In this circuit, when in bar mode all LEDs light up, in dot mode only LD10s. Overall it doesn't react to the audio input at all.
I wanted to use a half wave rectifier before the LM3914 for better precision. Since I use a single supply, I fed half of it to the non-inverting pin of the TL072.
I am doing something wrong but I don't know what it is.

Do you have a multimeter? Measure the voltage out of your precision rectifiers. Do you have a potentiometer, or a pair of resistors to make a varying voltage? Put various DC voltages into pin 5 of the lm3914. What ahppens?

Wiring RV1 and RV2 as shown is not a good solution ... Also, remove C8 and C9.

If you add a TO-92 78L05 + 8-pin ICL7660 (with some caps) you can generate -5V just for the op-amps and get rid of R11/R12. The pots can remain wired as they are. Get rid of C8/C9.
You could also redesign it to use a single 12V supply as you have with some effort, but the way it is now, the inverting inputs are at 0V and they need to be at +1.5V or more for the op-amps you have to function. The output has to be referred to 0V for the LM391x to work over the full range. If you want to pursue this, I suggest looking at single-supply precision rectifier circuits.
For example this is a full-wave (semi) precision rectifier with an output low-pass filter.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You won't get very good results for a VU meter - the LM3914 is a linear bar-graph driver. The LM3915 was designed for this purpose and has 3dB steps.
Simulating the response of a real VU meter is a more involved subject.

thank you. I will check it out. Why the LPF at the end? Unfortunately the LM34915 is gone, I also believe that the 3914 is EOL. Not many choices left.

The low pass filter, which is R6/C4 and R5/C3 in your circuit and R8/C3 in @Antonio's circuit is to try to get a response that is useful. A real VU meter is suppose to have a rise time (to 99%, not 63%) of ~300ms and similar fall time, which would imply a longer time constant (eg. higher value for R4) than I've shown. Maybe 30k to 50k.

P.S. A compatible chip to the (originally National Semiconductor) LM3915 is made by Shenzhen HTCSEMI P/N HT3915A.

The LM3914 measures a DC input signal.
C8 and C9 are blocking the DC.

I added C8 and C9 in a troubleshooting attempt. Without them same problems as described

You should correct your circuit ... wiring RV1 and RV2 to the "Half" point .
You should include a little resistor as I did, but it is not the best "wiring".
The input amplitude generator is set to 100 mV peak.
You should see the output varying from half supply voltage to quasi full supply.
The output should be "adapted" at the input of the LM3914 ... or vice-versa.


Ok thanks I will try it as you wrote. Just why you add the 1k resistor? and what do you mean by it is not the best wiring?

The 1k resistor is to let a little resistor below the RV pot. Not very important. If it works, then all is ok.
